# How to set Default Organization of Sentry.io using sentry-cli

Tags: android, android-studio, terminal, sentry

I'm going to use Sentry for My Android app. My company is using a self-hosted Sentry, version 9.0.0. I get the below answer when I run `sentry-cli info` command using sentry-cli:

```
Sentry Server: https://log.mydomain.com
Default Organization: -
Default Project: -
```

It didn't recognize **Default Organization** and **Default Project**. How can I set these data?

Answer (score 1):

Did you define the Sentry Project and Organization somewhere?

Some commands require your Sentry Organization and/or Projects slugs.
There are multiple ways to provide these values:

- Command line argument, like; --org
- Environment variables, like; SENTRY_ORG
- Adding to a configuration file

[As per the docs](https://docs.sentry.io/cli/configuration/#configuration-file):

You can add to the configuration file (`~/.sentryclirc`) the keys: 
`defaults.project`
`defaults.org`

Or use the environment variables: `SENTRY_PROJECT` and `SENTRY_ORG`

Comment: No, I didn't. I didn't understand your answer exactly. Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: Sorry i have hard time to understand your answer. can you give en example, please.

Comment: OK I tried to clarify the answer a bit. let me know if it's clearer now